# Is there a way to bind DNS port 53 to only TCP or UDP specifically?

Tags: python, sockets, dns, python-sockets

I need to keep dns port 53 busy/binded to a interface over only TCP or only UDP. is there a way to accomplish this? using socket lib python or any other way would be appreciated.

Comment: Does that mean 2 socket will be made, TCP and UDP, but only one can accept a connection at a time? you can implement it using `select.select`.

Comment: Hi Hagai, Actually only one socket at a time needed. it can be either TCP or UDP, but port 53 of interface should be binded over one transport protocol.

Comment: Can you explain why? It is not a problem technically, but port 53 for DNS needs both TCP and UDP to work reliable in all cases (despite old documentation stating that TCP is only for zone transfers, which is completely wrong).

Comment: Hi Patrick, Yeah I agree(AXFR  and other DNS stuffs uses TCP), But I need these for testing, where it should use/listen to  whichever left interfaces:Proto(TCP or UDP):53. That's why i want to keep eitheir TCP or UDP busy(but not both) with another service or any other means at one time.

Answer (score -1):

tcp only

```
from socket import *

tcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcp.bind(('', 53))
tcp.listen(5)
```

udp only

```
from socket import *

udp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
udp.bind(('', 53))
```

Comment: And if you do both it isn't 'TCP only' or 'UDP only'.

Comment: yeah exactly @EJP, I tried these, binding to eth0 interface IP. didn't get what i expected.